# Is it possible to implement a shadow effect on a transparent element in WPF using DropShadowEffect?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was wondering if it is possible to apply a shadow effect to a transparent element in wpf. Does anyone know how to implement a shadow in an element without background.

I tried this [DropShadowPanel.cs](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF/blob/9acc2519f36c60e830c4603d01363c5bfa8909b5/FluentWPF/DropShadowPanel.cs) but unfortunately DropShadowPanel does not support rounded corners.

Thanks a lot.

```
<Border
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    Background="Transparent">
     <Border.Effect>
       <DropShadowEffect
         BlurRadius="14"
         Direction="270"
         Opacity=".42"
         RenderingBias="Performance"
         ShadowDepth="4.5"
         Color="Black" />
    </Border.Effect>
 </Border>
```

Comment: No. It's a gaussian blur based effect. It is sort of averaging pixel colour so it needs some colour there to average. Transparent means there's nothing to average.